# How to auto start a WCF windows service upon server start using configuration settings

Tags: asp.net, wcf, windows-services, app-config

I am looking to find a solution to auto start a WCF Windows service using any settings in the config file. Appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Putting an entry in the Config file will not make any program start automatically. Something else, different than the service itself -or whatever program- would need to check the value in the Config file and determine whether the service should be started or not.

Alternatively, you could configure the service to always start automatically and either continue running if certain value is present in the Config file or shutdown itself otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Using config file won't solve your problem. Instead, you should install your WCF windows service as a windows service by using InstallUtil command. Then, you can mark your service as auto start one in services.msc